# jqGrid setSelect function with parametrized query

Tags: php, jquery, parameters, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid, on edit/add function I want to have a drop down list in one of these fields.

This works if i use the setSelect function as this:

```
$grid->setSelect("title", "SELECT DISTINCT name,name as TestingName FROM template", true, true, false, array(""=>"All"));
```

How can I pass parameters to my query? I tried these:

1-`"SELECT DISTINCT name,name as TestingName FROM template where tempid = ?"`

2- `"SELECT DISTINCT name,name as TestingName FROM template where tempid = $rowid"`

3-`"SELECT DISTINCT name,name as TestingName FROM template where tempid = ". $rowid`

none of the above worked while having:

```
if(isset ($_REQUEST["tempid"]))
    $rowid = jqGridUtils::Strip($_REQUEST["tempid"]);
else
    $rowid = "";
```

Comment: i can't find any documentation about the `->setSelect` method of the jqgrid php class on http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/docs/jqGrid/jqGrid.html#sec-method-summary can you provide some more information?

Comment: http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/index.htm -> section tutorials->drop downs

Answer (score 4):

If I correct understand your question you use [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) with `dataUrl`. You want to have the URL which has additional parameter `tempid` which value should be the rowid of the current selected row.

From the syntax of your question I suppose that you use some commercial jqGrid for PHP product from [trirand.net](http://www.trirand.net/). In the case you should use tag [jqgrid-php]. jqGrid is pure JavaScript open source product. So I answer how you can add `dataUrl` parameter in JavaScript.

jqGrid has [ajaxSelectOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option which can be used to *modify* the `jQuery.ajax` options of the call which use `dataUrl`. You can do following

```
var myGrid = $("#list");

myGrid.jqGrid({
    // all your current parameters of jqGrid and then the following
    ajaxSelectOptions: {
        data: {
            tempid: function () {
                return myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If the `data` parameter of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) contain a method instead of a property the method will be called every time of the corresponding `jQuery.ajax` call. I used the same trick in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819).

Comment: the tempid is the primary key of the master grid, im sending it the detail grid, and i can get the value of the tempid in the detail grid. my problem  is that i don't know how to use the setSelect function to pass query with parameter

Comment: @Grace: I see no difference. You can just `myMasterGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');` in the detail grid. Alternatively you can save the id of the current selected row of the master grid in a variable (like `masterRowId`). You can do this inside the `onSelectRow` event of the master grid. Then you can use `tempid: function () { return masterRowId; }`

Comment: @Grace: Probably you use `ajaxSelectOptions` in the wrong place. I modified a little my answer to show more clear that you should add `ajaxSelectOptions` to other jqGrid options which you use.