# jqgrid dropdowns pass value of another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jqgrid

I am using `jqGrid` to show data in tabular format, using `JSP` and `Servlet`.

I have two *dependent drop-downs* to show.

1. Show State
2. Show City

Following is relevant code:

```
colNames:['User ID', 'Name','State','City'], 
colModel:[
{name:'USERID',index:'USERID',....},
{name:'NAME',index:'NAME',....},
{
name:'STATE',
index:'STATE',
width:125,
sortable:true,
edittype:"select",
editoptions: {
    maxlength: 15,
    dataUrl: 'MYServlet?action=getState',
    dataEvents :[{ 
        type: 'change',
        fn: function(e) {
            var thisval = $(e.target).val();
            $.post('MyServlet?action=getCity='+thisval,
            function(data){
                var res = $(data).html();
                $("#STATE").html(res);
            });
        }
    }]
}
},
{
    name:'CITY',
    index:'CITY',
    width:125,
    sortable:true,
    editable:true,
    edittype:"select",
    editoptions:{maxlength: 50 , value: 'Select:Select'}
}
],
```

Above code is working fine for *dependent drop-downs*. Now I want to pass `USERID` with `datUrl`  in `editoptions` of `STATE` column. like

```
dataUrl: 'MYServlet?action=getState&userid='+userid
```

But I am not able to get `USERID` in `dataUrl`.

So any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested some extensions of `dataUrl` which are now part of jqGrid. It's usage of `postData` property of `editoption` defined as function (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14952082/315935)) or usage of `dataUrl` as function directly (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/support-dataurl-as-function/#p27702) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/108d04eeabbb2eb4bd24a14415a892a68604a1fa)). The first feature is included in jqGrid 4.4.2, but the second is included *after* 4.5.2 was released. So I recommend you to use `postData` as function.

What you need to do is adding `postData` property to `editoptions` of `STATE` column in the form

```
editoptions: {
    dataUrl: "MYServlet",
    postData: function (rowid) {
        return {
            action: "getState",
            userid: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "USERID")
        };
    }
}
```

If the values of `USERID` column is unique and you use `key: true` then rowid are already the same value as the value of `USERID` column. In the case you can simplify the above code and use `rowid` directly instead of `$(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "USERID")`.

Comment: Can you help me for this Question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534548/how-to-load-data-in-jqgrid-column-in-jsp-from-database