# dynamic dropdown with additional parameter in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Although there were several links regarding dynamic dropdown .after using those links i could not get expected result.I am able to get dynamic  dropdown from php.But dont know how to pass parameter in editoption.Could any one suggest this.

**how to get current row id .i want to pass it as id. in below shown**:

Here is the code for jqgrid colmodel:

```
colModel:[{name:'proof',index:'proof', width:50,formoptions:{rowpos:4, colpos:2},editable:true,edittype:"select",
editoptions: { dataUrl:"http://27.251.54.45/lighthouse/dynamicversion.php?id=" +id}},]
```

php code:

```
include("include/connect.php");

$jobid=$_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT  r.revisionid FROM revision r JOIN revision v
          ON r.versionid = v.versionid and r.jobid=$jobid";


echo "<select id='proof'>
<option value='New Version'>New Version</option>
<option value='New Revision'>New Revision</option>";
$result = mysql_query ($query,$connect);
while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "<option value=$cat[0]>$cat[1]</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Could any one please give suggestion on this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all you should never include prefix like `http://27.251.54.45/` in the URL used for Ajax requests if you don't use JSONP.

If I understand correctly your problem you should follow my suggestion from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14952082/315935) and my [pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/404) which is a part of current version of jqGrid. So to solve your problem you should modify `editoptions` of the column to the following

```js
editoptions: {
    dataUrl: "/lighthouse/dynamicversion.php",
    postData: function (rowid) {
        return { id: rowid };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg thank for your quick response .But still i am not getting id being posted in dynamicversion.php.is there any thing else i need to modify

Comment: @user762641: You are welcome! Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: since i m working on maintainence i m not very sure.But most probably it is 4.1.1

Comment: @user762641: You should upgrade jqGrid to the current jqGrid version 4.4.5 (you can download it [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)). [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952082/315935) which I referenced says that the feature are implemented starting with 4.4.2 version and then improved in more recent version.

Comment: is it not possible to modify only few core files .Because i dont which are old jqgrid files and  modified files

Comment: @user762641: It's bad way, but if you want you can follow the changes which I described in [my pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/3e2a0ada37357e717f17acfcfd0289a7a0800427). Alternatively you can follow [more old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8067258/315935).

Comment: Thanks again Oleg.Difficult to imagine Jqgrid without Oleg.For me jqgrid is synomous with oleg

Comment: Oleg, this does not work for me either. Jqgrid is a source of much frustration for me - no examples or help available.

Comment: @sarsnake: What you did? **Which version and from which fork of jqGrid you use?** Which examples you want to have? I posted very much demos in my old answer and I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I provide for free. For example `dataUrl` can be function in free jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.3/js/grid.common.js#L452)) and `postData` too (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.3/js/grid.common.js#L455)).